# ImportError:lib/arm-linux-gnueabihr/libstdc++.So.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found

Tags: linux, tensorflow, yolov7

Is there any way I can solve this error. I'm trying to run a yolov7 model converted and quantized into tflite. I'm  using tflite_runtime to run it on raspberry pi 4, aarch 64, but this error keep popping up. Any help? I used colab to convert the model.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.